# How to count number of deleted rows from one table in delete + join structure?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I use the following query, to delete the rows from two tables

```
delete 
     itc, ic 
from 
     incoming_tours ic 
join 
     incoming_tours_cities itc on itc.id_parrent = ic.id 
where 
     ic.sale = '5'
```

How can i get the number of affected rows from ic table? ([mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) returns the total count, i need only from one table). 
(I use MyISAM engines in my tables, that is why i don't use foreign keys here)

Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the rows beforehand.

```
select count(*) as sale_rows from ic where ic.sale = '5'
```

Do it in a transaction to make sure the table does not change between the SELECT and DELETE commands.

Comment: So there is no way to make this in single query?

Comment: @Syom: No, I guess not. Mind game: How would you imagine this should work? The "delete from multiple tables" syntax imposes no limit on how many tables you can delete from. How should `mysql_affected_rows()` know which number you want to see? It accepts no arguments, after all.

Comment: yes, i agree, but i thought maybe i can modify the query someway, to reach the effect.

Comment: @Syon: You could try experimenting with foreign keys and ON DELETE CASCADE. This way you could delete from one table only, which would give an accurate count with `mysql_affected_rows()`. In any case, being explicit with an extra SELECT does not hurt, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use affected_rows for this. I think you can use a session variable in an after delete trigger on ic to count deleted rows.